# Finding cells within range on a hexagonal grid

Tags: php, hexagonal-grid

I'm looking for a way to get the cells based on a N range. But no luck.

I'm converting Row Column offset to Cube Coordinate system QR -> XYZ

```
$range = 1;
for ($dx = -$range; $dx <= $range; $dx++)
{
    for ($dy = max(-$range, -$dx - $range); $dy <= min($range, -$dx + $range); $dy++)
    {
        $dz = -$dx-$dy;
        $points = $hexagon->cube_to_oddq(array($dx,$dy,$dz));
        $x = $hexagon->ver + $points[0] * $hexagon->size * 1.5;
        $y = $hexagon->height + $points[1] * $hexagon->height + ( ($points[0]%2) * ( $hexagon->height / 2 ) ); 
        $points = $hexagon->drawHex($x,$y, true);
        $pointss = array();
        foreach($points as $p) {
            $pointss[] = $p[0];
            $pointss[] = $p[1];
        }
        imagefilledpolygon ( $png_image , $pointss , 6 , $black );
    }
}
```

Result:
Inside every hex cell
(First line is QR coordinate)
(Second line is XYZ converted coordinate)

[image: Hexagon]

Any advice what I'm doing wrong?

Update:

As requested, the Oddq (Q,R) to Cube conversion XYZ

```
    $i = $hex[0] = ROW
    $j = $hex[2] = COLUMN
    public function oddq_to_cube($hex){
        $hex[2] = $hex[1];
        $x = $hex[2];
        $z = $hex[0] - ($hex[2] - ($hex[2]&1)) / 2;
        $y = -$x-$z;
        return array($x, $y, $z);
    }
    $curr_cube = $hexagon->oddq_to_cube(array($i,$j));
```

Comment: Your conversion from offset columns to cube coordinates is not correct. Reading along a line of neighbouring hexes, we should see the same cube coordinate offset to each successive neighbour. eg. if going down from (0, 0, 0) took me to (-1, 0, 1), then a taking another step down should take me to (-2, 0, 2), then (-3, 0, 3) etc. But your xyz coordinate offsets *change* as we read along a line. We'd need to see the code for your conversion to diagnose what's going wrong inside it.

Comment: Dear @DMGregory, updated the question.

Comment: As posed, the question still doesn't have enough information to answer the question. For example, the coordinates in the screenshot do not actually match the dx, dy, dz code in the question, and you posted the code for `oddq_to_cube` while the original question only used `cube_to_oddq`. I'm also confused whether your variables `$x` and `$y` are  in  (X, Y, Z) as cubical coordinates or x, y as screen coordinates, as well as the intended behavior or `drawHex` and `imageFilledPolygon`.

Comment: Let me upload the full code.

Comment: @Jimmy https://pastebin.com/0EvVm011 and the class is this https://pastebin.com/P6STfgbL

Comment: Related: [Finding cells within range on hexagonal grid](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/116035/finding-cells-within-range-on-hexagonal-grid/116087) (using C#).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the "offset-q" coordinate system mixed up with the cubical coordinate system. In general, it's easier to translate from the cubical coordinates to screen coordinates because it's a simple linear transformation.

```
for ($dx = -$range; $dx <= $range; $dx++)
{
    for ($dy = max(-$range, -$dx - $range); $dy <= min($range, -$dx + $range); $dy++)
    {
        $x = 96 + $hexagon->ver + $hexagon->size * 1.5 * $dx;
        $y = 54.6 + $hexagon->height + $hexagon->height * $dy + $hexagon->height/2 * $dx;
        $points = $hexagon->drawHex($x,$y, true);
        ...
```

Comment: It works excellent now !
Looks like i need to have a better understand on the coordinates system.
Now i need to find the way to get the range from a given offset.
Thanks so much @jimmy !